# undefined symbol: Tk_Init

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

python2.7
when I import Tkinter, it prompt no module named _tkinter, I don't have the limits of administrator, so I install tcl and tk, then recompile python with --with-tcltk-includes and --with-tcltk-libs parameter, but when running 'make', the error """*** WARNING: renaming "_tkinter" since importing it failed: build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/_tkinter.so: undefined symbol: Tk_Init""" occurred, I really don't know how to deal with it
can somebody help me?
thanks!

Comment: Python 2.7 should have Tkinter installed. But - for example - on the newest Ubuntu you have to install it manually using Ubuntu `apt install python-tk`

Answer (score 1):

Both the -L and -l flags are needed in the parameter --with-tcltk-libs. I got the same error as you when I only used the -L flag.

In my case, this worked:

```
./configure --prefix=$PREFIX --with-tcltk-includes="-I$PREFIX/include" --with-tcltk-libs="-L$PREFIX/lib/ -ltcl8.6 -ltk8.6"
```

You may need to change the version number in the name of the TCL and TK libraries (and of course define $PREFIX).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue with Python-3.4.3. I followed Brice's solution and got halfway there. Not only did I require the -l flags after the -L flag as he suggested, but I discovered my LD_LIBRARY_PATH was inadequate when performing the 'make altinstall'. Be sure to include the same directory in LD_LIBRARY_PATH as used in your -L flag entry.